# UWP c# creating a file in ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder returns null

Tags: c#, windows, file, xaml, uwp

I created an app that needs to store user data in a file that is created on Application start and when I compile it, it shows me this *System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not find or load a specific file. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131621)* and this *System.NullReferenceException: Invalid pointer*.

When the Application starts it calls the `Init()` Method before everything.

```
    public static class FilesManager
    {

        public static StorageFolder ROOT_DIRECTORY, USER_DIRECTORY;
        public static StorageFile FILES_MANAGER_CACHE_FILE;

        public static volatile string FILES_MANAGER_CACHE;
        public static volatile StorageFolder FOLDER;

        public static async Task Init()
        {
            try
            {
                FOLDER = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFolderAsync("DashData", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
                FOLDER = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFolderAsync("DashData");
                if (FOLDER == null) Debug.WriteLine("FOLDER IS NULL.");
                FILES_MANAGER_CACHE_FILE = await FOLDER.CreateFileAsync("filesmanageruserdata.json", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
                FILES_MANAGER_CACHE_FILE = await FOLDER.GetFileAsync("filesmanageruserdata.json");
                await LoadFilesManagerCacheAsync();
                
                Debug.WriteLine("TEXT: " + FILES_MANAGER_CACHE);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("ERROR: " + e.ToString());
            }
        }

        public static async Task LoadFilesManagerCacheAsync()
        {
            FILES_MANAGER_CACHE = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(FILES_MANAGER_CACHE_FILE); 
        }
        
        public static async Task storeUserData(string content)
        {
            try
            {
                await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(FILES_MANAGER_CACHE_FILE, content);
            }catch(Exception e)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("ERROR: " + e.ToString());
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Could you please tell me where you called the `init` method? I tested your code in a blank UWP app and call the `init` method before ` Window.Current.Activate();` in the `OnLaunched` method in App.xaml.cs. It doesn't show any exceptions.

Comment: The `Init` method is called on in the first line of the `App.xaml.cs` constructor before everything. I can't call it in the `OnLaunched` method because I need it to load userdata that will be used in other classes and controls. Anyway thanks for your response.

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue even if I put the `init` method before ` this.InitializeComponent();` of the `App()` Method which should be the first method to call when launching an app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried different solution but none of them worked, while it had nothing to do with calling `await FilesManager.Init();` nor its implementation or anything else, I just switched to WinUI 3 Unpackaged App, its better than UWP as I know, good thing didn't find any real problem doing async stuff and reading/writing data. I only found some minor issues related to startup time of the app (which I think will be fixed in later releases of WinUI), anyway I recommend switching to it (it contains the same features of UWP and more, also it runs on dotnet core so the app could be made independent from the installation of dotnet runtime)